# How to find and up-to-date software on my machine?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, nautilus

Some times ago I download `VirtualBox` and I know exactly that it is exist on my machine because I can find it in the [DASH](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html) menu.

But where it is stored in Nautilus?

Also, how can I up-to-date my `VirtualBox`? I know that new version was released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download from: [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) the latest version of `VirtualBox`

Open Terminal in the downloaded file location and type:

To Install deb package:

```
sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE
```

where `DEB_PACKAGE` is the downloaded file

To remove deb package:

```
sudo dpkg -r PACKAGE_NAME
```

where `PACKAGE_NAME` is the correct package you want to remove.
Recommended to press <kbd>TAB</kbd> for autocomplete the full package name.

Sometimes you'll need to install missing to complete the installation, it can be done by:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

To see where is app you can use:

```
whereis appname
```

**About whereis:**

```
whereis locates source/binary and manuals sections for specified files.
```

or

```
which appname
```

**About which:**

```
which returns the pathnames of the files which would be executed in the current environment
```

Comment: Just now i redonload virtual box again from ubuntu center, but how i can know if it is the newest version? is there any way to check?

Comment: You can always see the latest version in the download link i specify. or from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: I mean version that i have downloaded... How i can know exactly number? i want it to compare)

Comment: If you not install Virtualbox yet, you can see the version from where you download the Virtualbox. if it already installed you can enter to Virtualbox and go to Help > About VirtualBox. There you will see the current version number

Comment: i edded picture of my virtual box and there is no Help button

Comment: Go to `System Settings` > `Appearance` > `Behavior`. and select show the menu for a window: `in the window's title bar`. after this you will see the menu in the current window title bar. Currently right now you can see it at the top left side in your screen.

Comment: Ok, but as you see according my screenshot button Settings is not availabale. Do you know another way to do it?

Comment: Open the DASH and type System Settings, Press Enter. or Right click on Desktop > `Change Background` > `Behavior` . Now select show the menu for a window: `in the window's title bar`.

Comment: Or Just Open Terminal and Type: `VBoxManage --version`

Answer (score 0):

## General

It depends how you installed virtualbox (or any other software) in the first place.

## Regarding typical locations of executables

Assuming you installed an application using apt, the executables are usually located in `/usr/bin/`.

**Example:**

Firefox can be found in `/usr/bin/firefox`.

You can easily check that using the `which` command:

**Example:**

`which firefox`

outputs:

`/usr/bin/firefox`

In addition there is `whereis`.

**Example:**

`whereis firefox`

outputs:

```
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib/firefox /etc/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
```

## Regarding updating to latest version

Assuming you installed the software in question using the default method (apt) you could easily upgrade it to the latest available version of your Ubuntu version using

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It might happen that your current Ubuntu version is offering an older version then (for example) a custom / 3rd party source, in which case you have to decide if you want to use the comfort way using Ubuntu sources or focusing on having the latest version - from a foreign source.

Comment: i remember that i install virtual box from Ubuntu Center... Where Ubuntu Center stored software?

Comment: The executable is located in  `/usr/bin/virtualbox`

Comment: no... not there

Comment: I would guess then that you downloaded a .deb manually and installed it by hand (and did not use apt/Software Center or similar)

Comment: sorry i found it) Thanks! maybe you know how i can check version of virtual box? some terminal commands?